# Using wp-uploads instead of wp-content/uploads

Tags: configuration, uploads, linux

What is the difference between the `wp-uploads` directory and the `wp-content/uploads` directory?  I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 and recently installed WordPress using apt-get, but there have been a few problems.

Most of the install went into `/usr/share/wordpress` including a `wp-content` directory, but inside that, there is no `upload` directory.  Instead, in `/srv/www` there is a symbolic link to the main directory, and a `wp-uploads` directory.  After changing the permissions of `/srv/www`, I am able to upload things, but not access them via any URL.

Any ideas **how** to properly WordPress to serve stuff from `/srv/www/wp-uploads`?  Any ideas **why** it's installed like that?  Should I just delete it, and reconfigure to use `wp-content/uploads` like everyone else?

Comment: This is a server configuration issue and a "let's build our own script that tries to do things in a way that WordPress wasn't designed" issue, but [Apache's `FollowSymLinks` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after lots of digging (before and after posting this question), I think I figured it out.  As @s_ha_dum suggests, the reason behind the odd directory placement is likely a personal preference of the person who created the Ubuntu "wordpress" package.  Perhaps it makes for easier partitioning of permissions, or it makes updates more safe (in case the entire wp-content directory is replaced).

In any case, my problem accessing uploads with a URL came from the fact that I configured the Apache virtual host myself.  My configuration did allow `FollowSymLinks`, but there was not a symlink in `/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content` nor did I think to make an alias to the clandestine upload directory.  After running `sudo apt-get install wordpress` I ran the MySQL setup script (`/usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql`) but did not notice the example Apache2 config file at `/usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/apache.conf`.  That would have helped.

In the end, I just created an `upload` directory within `wp-content` like normal people do, and configured for that.  It worked like a charm.  Then, because the repository version was a few versions old, I also had to manually upgrade to the latest version of WordPress, which worked refreshingly well!  Ultimately, I hope this helps someone else out in the same predicament, but if I had to do it again, I would probably install from the WordPress website.

Answer (score 3):

I created a symbolic link in the /var/www/ directory.

```
ln -s /srv/www/wp-uploads/ wp-uploads
```

and then (in settings-> media) set up the upload folder:

```
wp-uploads
```

and url path:

```
http://<my-ip>/wp-uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed everything in /srv/www and created a wp-uploads directory in the web-root (e.g var/www or mysite/public). This makes sense in particular when you have multiple websites using wordpress. /usr/share/wordpress is then used for common files and wp-uploads is in the site specific directory.

Remember to change the site specific config in /etc/wordpress.